# Saving JSON responce to NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

This is what my `JSON` return;

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "Sharon",
        "telephone": "48-9929329483"

    },
    "2": {
        "name": "Sage",
        "telephone": "48-9560333267"
    },
    "3": {
        "name": "Alex",
        "telephone": "48-8467982378"
    }
}
```

I need to save this in a NSDictionary. My workings are as follows;

```
 NSDictionary *contentOfDictionary = [responseString JSONValue];

NSDictionary* studentDictionary = [contentDictionary objectForKey:@"1"];
NSString *nameOfStudent = [studentDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *nameOfStudent = [studentDictionary objectForKey:@"telephone"];

NSDictionary* studentDictionary1 = [contentDictionary objectForKey:@"2"];
NSString *nameOfStudent1 = [studentDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *nameOfStudent1 = [studentDictionary objectForKey:@"telephone"];

..... etc
```

So this is what i do to save the attributes to `dictionaries` and `strings`. But the problem is that i am hard-coding the key value `1,2,3 etc`.. (ex: `[contentDictionary objectForKey:@"2"];`)

In reality i don't know how many students will the `JSON` file have. There might be 100 or even more. So how can i write this in a way where the code will automatically, read JSON response (all 100 records) and save it to `NSDictionary` and vice versa ?

note: I guess i have to use a for loop or something.

Comment: It depends what you are going to do with the data once you extract it. I'd recommend you start with some basics of programming like arrays and control structures like loops (for, while, etc).

Comment: I need to display the content on to a tableview. I have done this several times before, but i am unable to extract values from this particular JSON response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a dictionary in 'contentsOfDictionary' where the keys are "1", "2", ... and the values are dictionaries containing the names/telephone numbers. So you just need to iterate through all the values:

```
NSMutableArray *studentDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *studentDictionary in contentOfDictionary.allValues)
{
    [studentDictionaries addObject:studentDictionary];
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what `allValues` does?

Comment: `allValues` returns an array of all the values in the dictionary. In fact you could simplify that code to just `NSArray *studentDictionaries = contentOfDictionary.allValues;` if that's all you need to do.

Comment: *Important note:* the order is undefined in a dictionary. (It may show up in the expected order most of the time, but this isn't guaranteed.) It'd be better to use `allKeys` and sort those first. Then use those to iterate over the `contentOfDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

If each dictionary entry in your JSON response is uniquely numbered and increasing without gaps, then you could do the following:

```
NSMutableArray *studentDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSUInteger index = 1;
NSDictionary *studentDictionary;
while (studentDictionary = [contentDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", index++]]) {
    [studentDictionaries addObject:studentDictionary];
}
```

Comment: What hapense if the `index` becomes 10, and there isn't an indexr 10, in the `contentDictionary` dictionary. There will be an exception (index out of bound). How can i handle it?

Comment: Because `studentDictionaries` is an NSDictionary and not an NSArray, you won't get an exception here.  NSDictionary will return `nil` for a key which doesn't exist.  Since the assignment to studentDictionary occurs in the while condition, if the result is nil, then the loop will stop.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) available since iOS5 (or SBJSON framework). You'll get your JSON parsed and embedded in obj-c objects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `NSDictionary` to store `responsestring` `JSONValue`

```
 NSDictionary *contentOfDictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
```

use `NSArray` to store `responsestring` `JSONValue`

```
  NSArray *arr= [responseString JSONValue];
```

In this way you will get the total count ,each object in the array is a dictionary which can be accessed easily.